# Unpack binary data read from serial port in LabVIEW

Tags: labview, visa

I am reading data from 3, 12bit ADCs and streaming the data constantly to computer by USB (UART) . Each package of the data stream is as follows:

[image: image of data]

It has 6 bytes of data  from 3 ADCS which the 8 bits LSB of each ADC is in one byte and the rest 4 bits MSB is in another byte. Also there are 2 bytes with "z" and "y" character at the end of the package of data to realize the start and end of each package. How do I unpack this data with LabVIEW?

Comment: This data consists of 6 bytes that could be any value followed by two bytes that are literally ASCII `y` (0x79) and `z` (0x7A)? And by *constantly* you mean there is little or no time delay between the end of one package and the start of the next?

Comment: Also, have you tried anything in LabVIEW yet? If so please post your code, preferably by making a [VI Snippet](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/9330/en/) and adding it to your post as an inline image. And when you say *I am reading data…*, have you written the code that does this and if so can it be changed?

Comment: The ASCII is true, Yes there is no delay between the packages

Comment: I started but I have no idea how to unpack the data. I can read the data and show it in string indicator (very simple GUI)

Comment: Have a look at the type-cast function.

Comment: Sorry, my last comment wasn't quite clear. I meant have you written the code that transmits the data, and can that be changed? Is there any guarantee that the six data bytes can't contain the sequence 0x797A, i.e. `yz`, which would be misidentified as the end-of-package sequence?

Comment: no it is impossible six data bytes can't contain the sequence 0x797A,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for unpacking the data:
[image]